# styling the kendo grid- custom styles

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to remove the grey border around the grid header. How can this be done?
Here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/tmLmk/7/

Html code:

```
<div ng-controller="GridController">    
    <div kendo-grid k-options="options" k-data-source="sData"></div>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
angular.module('angular-kendo-example', ['kendo.directives']);

function GridController($scope) {
    $scope.options = {
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [{
            field: "column1",
            title: "column 1",
            width: "40px"
        },{
            field: "column2",
            title: "column 2",
            width: "70px"
        },{
            field: "column3",
            title: "column 3",
            width: "70px"
        },{
            field: "column4",
            title: "column 4",
            width: "60px"
        },{
            field: "column5",
            title: "column 5",
            width: "40px"
        },{
            field: "column6",
            title: "column 6",
            width: "40px"
        }],

    };
    $scope.sData= [
        { column1: "column1 data", column2: "column2 data", column3: "column3 data", column4:  "column4 data",  column5: "column5 data", column6: "column6 data"  }, { column1: "column1 data", column2: "column2 data", column3: "column3 data", column4:  "column4 data",  column5: "column5 data", column6: "column6 data"  }, { column1: "column1 data", column2: "column2 data", column3: "column3 data", column4:  "column4 data",  column5: "column5 data", column6: "column6 data"  }
    ];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean without changing the color of the other rows of the table ?

Comment: Yes, i just need to remove the thick header border in the grid, how can this be done?

Comment: I added an id to your data div in [your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmLmk/8/), but don't know Kendo. You may be interested in [Changing row template in Kendo UI](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/rowtemplate)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i can still see the grey border at the top of the header in the fiddle link you modified. How can that be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with a CSS solution, try this:

```css
.k-grid-header table[role='grid']{
    border-spacing:0px;
}
```

Let me know if this isn't the desired result.